# What do WSDL/XSD Annotations look like inside an SOAP Envelope?

Tags: xsd, wsdl

Does anybody have any examples of what an Annotation with Documentation or AppInfo children look like inside a SOAP Envelope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Annotations exist only in the WSDL. They never appear in a SOAP envelope.